# Referencing BrowserSync Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Having a hard time setting a typedef on an object defined in the [browser-sync type definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/browser-sync/browser-sync.d.ts).

The type definition looks like this:

```
declare module "browser-sync" {
    import chokidar = require("chokidar");
    import fs = require("fs");
    import http = require("http");

    interface Options {...}
    interface BrowserSyncStatic extends BrowserSyncInstance {
      (config?: Options, callback?: (err: Error, bs: Object) => any): BrowserSyncInstance;
    }
    interface BrowserSyncInstance {
      active: boolean;
      ...
    }
    const browserSync: BrowserSyncStatic;
    export = browserSync;
}
```

What I want to do is specify my `options` object as the type defined in the type definition, but I can't get the syntax right...

After importing it...

```
import * as browserSync from 'browser-sync';
```

I understand why methods like `active` are visible on the `browserSync` object (because it's the only thing that appears exported), but what I don't get is if I can even use the `Options` type that's defined within the type definition... it appears hidden from external use so I am left wondering what's the use of it being defined at all? I'm assuming my understanding is incorrect but can't figure out what I'm missing.

**EDIT:** Seems to be a known "issue" https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/6382